# Cant seem to play an audio file in my laravel app i stored the audio file to local storage when i try to play it using audio tag not playing

Tags: php, html, laravel

So I am uploading my mp3 file to local storage and save the path in the database so when i retrieve the record in the database and also the mp3 file its like the path is wrong as i cant seem to play it

I ran `php artisan storage:link` the uploads folder is inside the `storage/app/public/uploads` and this is where my audio files are

my controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Upload;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreUploadRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUploadRequest;

class UploadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $songs = Upload::all();
        return view('audio_upload.index', compact('songs'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('audio_upload.upload');
    }


    public function store(StoreUploadRequest $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validated();
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $fileName = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filePath = Storage::putFileAs('uploads', $file, $fileName);

        $upload = new Upload();
        $upload->title = $validatedData['title'];
        $upload->description = $validatedData['description'];
        $upload->file = $filePath;
        $upload->save();

        return redirect()->route('audio.index')->with('success', 'File uploaded successfully.');
    }

}
```

my index.blade.php

```php
@include('layout')



<div class="px-5">



<div class="w-9/12 rounded-lg justify-center mx-auto mt-8">
 <div class="flex space-x-4">
     <a href="/" class="">
         <button class="mt-4 bg-gray-700 w-48 h-10 rounded text-white">Back</button>
     </a>
     <a href="{{route('audio.create')}}" class="">
         <button class="mt-4 bg-gray-700 w-48 h-10 rounded text-white">Upload</button>
     </a>
 </div>


    <h1 class="font-sans text-transparent text-2xl bg-clip-text mt-4
        bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-700 to-blue-800">
        ALL Files
    </h1>

</div>

<div class="w-9/12 justify-center mx-auto mt-8">
    @if (session()->has('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success mt-3 font-sans text-gray-700 text-2xl justify-end">
            {{ session('success') }}
        </div>
    @endif
</div>


    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4 justify-center mx-auto mt-8 w-9/12">
        @foreach ($songs as $song)
            <div class="border border-gray-300 rounded-lg p-4">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/bg.png') }}" alt="nothing" width="7%" height="6%" class="rounded-b-3xl">
                <p class="text-base font-medium leading-none text-gray-700 mb-2">{{ $song->title }}</p>
                <p class="text-base leading-none text-gray-700 mb-2">{{ $song->description }}</p>
                <p class="text-sm leading-none text-gray-600">{{ $song->file }}</p>
                <audio controls class="mt-4">
                    <source src="{{ Storage::url($song->file) }}" type="audio/mp3">
                </audio>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

so when my default implementation failed tried using Facade storage to store and retrieve but still facing same issue also ran php artisan storage:link

Comment: `<source src="{{ Storage::url($song->file) }}"` - so what did this actually result in? Do you see any error messages in the console when you try to play the audio, or any error responses in the network panel?

Comment: Is this a PHP problem or a HTML problem? Are you sure that [tag:tailwind-css] is related?

Comment: So I think everyone's question here is how are you trying to play the file? Are you saying the file is corrupted?  Are you saying it can't be found? If you can find the file try to play it with a known working app, does it play?  please elaborate on a specific error.  "dd" is your friend!  ex: dd(get_defined_vars) or dd($somevarible)

Answer (score -1):

So here is how I figured it out - the controller logic was storing the audio files to the storage uploads folder but the blade logic was retrieving from the public folder, so thus the audio files were not playable.

So what I did is I changed the logic for retrieving the audio files.